# Testing Luminous rendering in clojure with core.test

Tags: clojure

This code is from the default luminus template:

```
(deftype RenderableTemplate [template params]
  Renderable
  (render
    [this request]
    (content-type
      (->>
        (assoc
          params
          (keyword (s/replace template #".html" "-selected"))
          "active"
          :servlet-context
          (:context request)
          :user-id
          (session/get :user-id)
          :user
          (session/get :user))
        (parser/render-file (str template-path template))
        response)
      "text/html; charset=utf-8")))

(defn render [template & [params]]
  (RenderableTemplate. template params))
```

And I need to test this function using clojure.test:

```
(defn home-page [& [user]]
  (layout/render
    "home.html"
   {:user user}))
```

How will I test the above function with the value associated to the key `:user`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read some documentation and make a reasonable effort before launching so general questions. This could be an start http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/08/clojuretest-introduction.html

After you feel a bit comfortable with clojure test you may like to move to https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/A-tutorial-introduction-for-Clojure.test-users

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

First set your routes and handlers like this:

```
(defn home-page [& [user]]
  (layout/render
    "home.html"
   {:user user}))


; setting routes
(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/user/:user" [user] (home-page user)))
```

Then do the unit testing:

**Basic unit test**

```
(deftest home-page-test
  ; Check if response code is 200
  (is (= 200 (:status (main-routes {:request-method :get :uri "/user/Michael"})))))
```

or you can also use [Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje)

**Using Midje**

```
(:use midje.sweet
      clojure.test)

(fact "Homepage Test"
  (:status (main-routes {:request-method :get :uri "/user/Michael")) => 200)
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem.
Calling (home-page) directly will return a RenderableTemplate type which isn't useful for testing.

In your test require:

```
(:require [capacityplanning.layout :as layout]
             [selmer.parser :as parser])
```

Add this function:

```
(def template-path "templates/")
(defn mockRender [template params]
  (parser/render-file (str template-path template) params))
```

And in your test you can bind:

```
(with-redefs [layout/render mockRender]
          (home-page user))
```

Now when home-page is called it will return the html as a string. This should be more useful to write unit tests against.